# Input voltage over frequency in lumped-element delay line?

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance, inductance

[image]
In a lumped delay lines, there is a reflected wave from the end of lines if the terminating impedance isn't equal to characteristic impedance. Therefore, at the input, the input voltage $V_{in}$ is from the superposition of the original wave and the reflected wave. As the frequency of the function generator changes, $V_{in}$ changes.

The graph below shows the relation between $V_{in}$ and frequency of the wave from function generator $f$ (done in an experiment). It looks like a sinusoidal curve.

My questions are:

1. Is there a equation(maybe sin function?) relating these two variables and how to derive it?
2. How to find time delay from these measurements?
3. Does time delay depend on frequency of the wave?

[image]

Comment: Hint: answer question 3 first, and use that answer to get the answers for 1 and 2.

Comment: another hint: approximate the LC line with a continuous transmission line, and calculate the reflection coefficient or input impedance while varying the frequency

Comment: @hyportnex isn't that the reflection coefficient depend only on terminating and characteristic impedance? How does it change with varying frequency?

Comment: see section "Input impedance" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflections_of_signals_on_conducting_lines . Question: How should you approximate the wave impedance of the line and what should be its length?

Comment: @hyportnex I looked for equation, that relate the impedance with the voltage propagation of the wave. $V=A(e^{i(\omega t-n\phi)}+re^{i(\omega t+n\phi)})$, where $r$ is reflection coefficient, $n$ is the number of the section. I was thinking of measuring the frequency between peaks, but I don't know if it's related. any hint is appreciated!

Comment: @ThePhoton Thanks. Can you give more details on solving question 3? like equations associated with time delay, frequency, and the measurements on this graph?

Comment: I was trying to obtain some physical quantities(e.g. attenuation, time delay, etc. ) by fitting this $V-f$ curve with a certain function which I want to find out. Because this curve can be fitted very well with sinusoidal waves. But I am trying to get the reasoning behind this.